# Would rsync overwrite the current files if I loose access to the files?

Tags: rsync

Would rsync overwrite to the current files that I have if I loose the access to certain data directories?

```
rsync -amHAXxzvR --update --numeric-ids --progress  --include='*/' --include=*.sas7bdat --exclude='*.old/' --exclude=* -e XXXXX@XXXX.XXXXX:/XXX/ /mnt/z/XXX/.
```

My permission to data can change every year or so depending on the institution access to the databases.
For example, for some files I get the following error if I dont have access:
failed to open "XXXX": Permission denied (13)

So, if I run the above command, will rsync overwrite and destroy the current files that I have already downloaded but lost access?

If so, how can I avoid it?
Thank you.

Comment: Quote the wildcard patterns like I did in my earlier answer. Protect them from the shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've not specified `--delete` so no files will be removed from the destination. You can test permissions very easily yourself.

Scenario

```
mkdir -p 739797/src 739797/dst
cd 739797

echo first try | tee src/file1 >src/file2         # Create two files
rsync -av src/ dst/                               # Copy everything
```

Using `ls -l` you can see that `dst/` now contains the same as `src/`

```
echo second attempt | tee src/file1 >src/file2    # Update the two files
chmod u= src/file2                                # Remove permission from file2
rsync -av src/ dst/                               # Attempt to copy everything
```

You'll see that `rsync` fails with permission denied on `file2`. Using `ls -l dst` you can see that `file1` has been updated but `file2` has not. Furthermore, `file` has (correctly) not been updated:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 roaima roaima 15 Mar 15 13:09 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 roaima roaima 10 Mar 15 13:04 file2
```

Extra notes

1. If you're backing up databases or indeed any other file with `rsync` bear in mind that it does not lock its source files while copying, and that the copying is not instantaneous. If the source file is changed while `rsync` is copying it, you may end up with undetected corruption in the  destination file. Backup snapshots or idle copies
2. Always quote the wildcard patterns for `--include` and `--exclude` so that the shell does not attempt to match them to files and directories in the filesystem. Instead of `--exclude=*` write `--exclude='*'`

Comment: Great explanation Roima. Thank you very much again.